# Function composition in R: compose versus %>%

Tags: r, functional-programming, purrr, magrittr

I am working with a code that make an extensive use of the function composition. Usually I use the `compose` function from the `purrr` package but it has some drawbacks, for instance if you print the composed function you don't get useful information.

```
log_sqrt_compose <- purrr::compose(log, sqrt)
print(log_sqrt_compose)

function (...) 
{
    out <- last(...)
    for (f in rev(rest)) {
        out <- f(out)
    }
    out
}
```

Instead with the pipe you can get a nicer results:

```
library(magrittr)
log_sqrt_pipe <- . %>% sqrt %>% log
print(log_sqrt_pipe)

Functional sequence with the following components:

 1. sqrt(.)
 2. log(.)

Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

Performing a benchmark it seems that the pipe solution is even faster

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(log_sqrt_compose(10), log_sqrt_pipe(10), times = 10000)
Unit: microseconds
                 expr   min    lq     mean median    uq    max neval
 log_sqrt_compose(10) 2.531 2.872 3.201496  3.058 3.296 54.786 10000
    log_sqrt_pipe(10) 2.007 2.411 2.767140  2.643 2.949 42.422 10000
```

Given the previous results, is there some other reason to prefer one of the two method in you experience?

**EDIT**:

Following @mt1022's comment I add also the base version

```
log_sqrt_f <- function(x) log(sqrt(x))
print(log_sqrt_f)

function(x) log(sqrt(x)) 



microbenchmark(log_sqrt_compose(10), log_sqrt_pipe(10), log_sqrt_f(10), times = 10000)
Unit: nanoseconds
                 expr  min   lq      mean median   uq     max neval
 log_sqrt_compose(10) 2529 2874 3151.7432   3052 3285  234039 10000
    log_sqrt_pipe(10) 2051 2474 2770.7148   2708 2990   16194 10000
       log_sqrt_f(10)  251  288  634.0649    341  420 2659789 10000
```

Comment: `log(sqrt(10))` is at least 10 times faster than both solutions above on my machine. Why not just write a simple function for this: `f <- function(x) log(sqrt(x))`? although `f` is slightly slower, it is still much faster than both of the above solutions.

Comment: I imagine the OP's real use of `compose` is probably much more complicated than the example provided(?) However, @mt1022's comment hints at my problem with both `compose` or pipes, is that they are harder to read compared to rolling your own functions in plain ol' `R`. The `compose` function is at least passable - but I really, really hate trying to read any code anyone writes using pipes. [And I'm not the only one :D](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2015/06/03/my-aversion-to-pipes/)

Comment: @HFBrowning Can you provide a more realistic example then (if you have something in mind)? I agree with you that my example maybe is a bit too simplistic :)

Comment: @amarchin not really - I was assuming that you yourself (since you said you use function composition a lot) had a more complicated reason why you didn't want to simply decompose your work into `log(sqrt(x))`